# NaN values when passing a Series to Series.map()

Tags: python, pandas

I may be going about this all the wrong way..
I am trying to find the postcodes of about 100 UK hospitals. I  have an Excel spread sheet (all_all) of the total number of hospitals/clinics/etc  in the Uk (14,000)  with their  addresses and postcodes.

I have a dataframe (spine) of surgical activity by year across these 100 hospitals with the hospital name repeated in 2817 rows.

```
spine.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2818 entries, 0 to 2817
Data columns (total 7 columns):
index_col       2818 non-null float64
fyear           2818 non-null int64
NNAPID          2818 non-null int64
mainspef        2818 non-null int64
Trust           2818 non-null object
complexcount    2818 non-null float64
simplecount     2818 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3), int64(3), object(1)
memory usage: 154.2+ KB
```

I thought I could use [Pandas series map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html).

importing csv including all 14,000 hospitals.

```
postcodes_all = pd.read_csv('all_all.csv')
```

```
postcodes_all.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 14206 entries, 0 to 14205
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Unnamed: 0     14206 non-null int64
Trust_title    14206 non-null object
postcode       14206 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 333.1+ KB
```

In the UK hospitals are Trusts so in my dataframe (spine) the column of hospital names = Trust. I am trying to map this to the hospital entries in postcodes_all (Trust_title).

```
     spine['Trust'].map(postcodes_all['Trust_title'])
        0       NaN
1       NaN
2       NaN
3       NaN
4       NaN
       ... 
2813    NaN
2814    NaN
2815    NaN
2816    NaN
2817    NaN
Name: Trust, Length: 2818, dtype: object
```

It is not finding any matches. The hospital fields are eg LEEDS TEACHING HOSPITALS NHS TRUST and the same entry is in postcodes_all.

Is there a way to explore why it has failed ?. I am a doctor trying to learn python and pandas for data analysis, so ver much early steps.

I am not sure if it hasn't failed and I just have the wrong datatype defined somewhere, or I am trying to match two columns that are inherently dissimilar and would like to be able to examine my failed code.

Sorry about the vagueness and brevity of the OP as I was rushing to clinic.

**Update**.

In light of Joe's comments below I have simplified things. From the spine csv I have defined the column to use as 'Trust', and in the postcode csv I have defined the index column as 'Trust'.

I am now definitely comparing the Hospital title in spine with the index field in postcodes.I now get a key error in 'Trust'.

and my code is here

```
import pandas as pd

spine = pd.read_csv('~/Dropbox/Work/NNAP/Spine/Kate_W/kate_spine2.csv', usecols = ['Trust'])



spine.head()

Trust
0   THE WALTON CENTRE NHS FOUNDATION TRUST
1   CAMBRIDGE UNIVERSITY HOSPITALS NHS FOUNDATION ...
2   KING'S COLLEGE HOSPITAL NHS FOUNDATION TRUST
3   LEEDS TEACHING HOSPITALS NHS TRUST
4   NT424

postcodes_all = pd.read_csv('all_all.csv', index_col = 'Trust')


postcodes_all.head()

    Unnamed: 0  postcode
Trust       
MANCHESTER UNIVERSITY NHS FOUNDATION TRUST  0   M13 9WL
SOUTH TYNESIDE AND SUNDERLAND NHS FOUNDATION TRUST  1   SR4 7TP
WORCESTERSHIRE HEALTH AND CARE NHS TRUST    2   WR5 1JR
SOLENT NHS TRUST    3   SO19 8BR
SHROPSHIRE COMMUNITY HEALTH NHS TRUST   4   SY3 8XL
```

To ensure I am using a series and not a dataframe I have added 'Trust' to the code as below.

```
map1 = spine['Trust'].map(postcodes_all['Trust'])

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2896             try:
-> 2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Trust'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-921448f7c401> in <module>
----> 1 map1 = spine['Trust'].map(postcodes_all['Trust'])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2993             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2994                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2995             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2996             if is_integer(indexer):
   2997                 indexer = [indexer]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:
-> 2899                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2900         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2901         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Trust'
```

I am not sure why this is incorrect and what the key error means.

Comment: Is it possible that you are trying to join two table together? Like a vlookup in Excel or a join in SQL? In that case, I'd use something like `spine.merge(postcodes_all, left_on="Trust", right_on="Trust_title", how="left")`. Also, I'd make sure that there are no duplicated rows in `postcodes_all`, because this may mess up the results you are looking for

Comment: Fabulous , this has worked brilliantly, - yes , vlookup was what I was after. I would still like to know why my map failed though , - see above, - or rather how to debug it. I was hoping to get a list of postcodes and then add that to the spine file, but your solution has done it all in one.

Comment: The reasons you get all `NaN` values is because none of the values in `spine['Trust']` are found in the index of `postcodes_all['Trust_title']`. `map()` is used to replace old values with new ones. It needs a key-value pair to know which new value to use when replacing each of the old values, for a series it using the index as the key and the single column as the value. My tips to how to debug things like this is to try with a simpler example, e.g. the one from the pandas documentation that you linked. I can expand with an example if the question gets reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get all NaN values is because none of the values in `spine['Trust']`
are found in the index of `postcodes_all['Trust_title']`.
`map()` is used to replace old values with new ones.
It needs a key-value pair to know which new value to use
when replacing each of the old values.
For a series,
it uses the index as the key and the single series column as the value.

A tip on how to debug in such situations,
is to try with a simpler example,
e.g. the one from the pandas documentation that you linked.
See below for an example.

```py
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['cat', 'dog', 'rabbit'])
s
```

```
## Output
0       cat
1       dog
2    rabbit
dtype: object
```

---

```py
s2 = pd.Series(['carnivore', 'omnivore', 'herbivore'])
s2
```

```
## Output
0    carnivore
1     omnivore
2    herbivore
dtype: object
```

---

```py
s.map(s2)
```

```
## Output
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
dtype: object
```

`NaN` is returned,
since pandas can't find any matching values between the values in `s`
and the index in `s2`.
Setting the index of `s2` to the values of `s` would solve this problem.

---

```py
# Set the values from `s` as the index in `s2`
s2.index = s
s2
```

```
## Output
cat       carnivore
dog        omnivore
rabbit    herbivore
dtype: object
```

---

```py
s.map(s2)
```

```
## Output
0    carnivore
1     omnivore
2    herbivore
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, In light of your helpful guidance I have updated as above in edit.

Comment: @capnahab Since you have assign `'Trust'` as the index, this column is no longer available in the `postcodes_all` dataframe. If the purpose of your call to `map()` is to replace the value of the `'Trust'` column in `spines` with the values of the `'postcode'` column in `postcodes_all`, then the following should work. `spine['Trust'].map(postcodes_all['postcode'])`

Comment: Many thanks Joe, yes thats what I was wanting. If I try _spine['Trust'].map(postcodes_all['postcode'])_ I get an indexing error and thats what out me down the track of trying to reassign the index (admittedly not much logic). The error is **InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects**. @joelostblom

Comment: @capnahab hmmm I am not sure I understand, my previous comment should work after reassign the index. Since this is a separate question from your original and it is difficult to explain in the comments, could you please ask a new question that only contains the relevant information for your new problem? If you can recreate the problem with a a simpler example that is easy to reproduce (such as the one from the documentation) that would be preferred but if it's not possible, go ahead and post your otogonal code instead. Feel free to link the question in a comment here and I can have a look.

Comment: Many thanks for your help Joe, I have opened another question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59319689/re-indexing-after-pandas-map

Comment: Many thanks Guys, - Especially joelostblom , KenHBS