# InvalidIndexError when trying to map Series with duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to map the names of hospitals to their UK postcodes. I have a csv of spine surgery in those hospitals (know as 'Trusts' in the UK), the csv is kate_spine.csv

I am importing one column from it (Trust) to simplify things.

```
import pandas as pd
spine = pd.read_csv('~/Dropbox/Work/NNAP/Spine/Kate_W/kate_spine2.csv', usecols = ['Trust'])
```

to show import:

```
spine.head()


Trust
0   THE WALTON CENTRE NHS FOUNDATION TRUST
1   CAMBRIDGE UNIVERSITY HOSPITALS NHS FOUNDATION ...
2   KING'S COLLEGE HOSPITAL NHS FOUNDATION TRUST
3   LEEDS TEACHING HOSPITALS NHS TRUST
4   NT424
```

These are the trust names and have an index.
My postcodes are in the csv all_all.csv. I am importing the file as one column, also 'Trust' to simplify. 
The format of the table is poor below but the postcodes are there.

```
postcodes_all = pd.read_csv('all_all.csv', index_col = 'Trust')
postcodes_all.head()

    Unnamed: 0  postcode
Trust       
MANCHESTER UNIVERSITY NHS FOUNDATION TRUST  0   M13 9WL
SOUTH TYNESIDE AND SUNDERLAND NHS FOUNDATION TRUST  1   SR4 7TP
WORCESTERSHIRE HEALTH AND CARE NHS TRUST    2   WR5 1JR
SOLENT NHS TRUST    3   SO19 8BR
SHROPSHIRE COMMUNITY HEALTH NHS TRUST   4   SY3 8XL
```

I am trying use map to get about 200 codes from a csv of 14,000. Here's my code:

```
spine['Trust'].map(postcodes_all['postcode'])
```

and the error:

```
InvalidIndexError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-25212fe14f16> in <module>
----> 1 spine['Trust'].map(postcodes_all['postcode'])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in map(self, arg, na_action)
   3826         dtype: object
   3827         """
-> 3828         new_values = super()._map_values(arg, na_action=na_action)
   3829         return self._constructor(new_values, index=self.index).__finalize__(self)
   3830 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in _map_values(self, mapper, na_action)
   1275                 values = self.values
   1276 
-> 1277             indexer = mapper.index.get_indexer(values)
   1278             new_values = algorithms.take_1d(mapper._values, indexer)
   1279 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_indexer(self, target, method, limit, tolerance)
   2983         if not self.is_unique:
   2984             raise InvalidIndexError(
-> 2985                 "Reindexing only valid with uniquely" " valued Index objects"
   2986             )
   2987 

InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

The spine file in the Trust column does contain duplicate values as each row describes the individual doctors surgical activity within the Trust and there will be up to 10 doctors (therefore 10 duplicate Trust names) in the series. I thought of trying this after extracting unique Trust names. Ideally though I would like to be able to do it to the series with its duplicates.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The spine file in the Trust column does contain duplicate values as each row describes the individual doctors surgical activity within the Trust and there will be up to 10 doctors (therefore 10 duplicate Trust names) in the series.

That's the issue. pandas does not know which value to use when there index duplicates. See the example below.

```py
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['cat', 'dog', 'rabbit', 'cat'])
s
```

```
## Out
0       cat
1       dog
2    rabbit
3       cat
dtype: object
```

```py
s2 = pd.Series(['carnivore', 'omnivore', 'herbivore', 'carnivore'])
# Set the value of `s` as the index of `s2`, since map looks at the Series index.
s2.index = s
s2
```

```
## Out
cat       carnivore
dog        omnivore
rabbit    herbivore
cat       carnivore
dtype: object
```

---

Since there are two occurrences of `cat` in the index of `s2`, pandas does not know which of their values to use when mapping `s2` to `s` (you can say that there is a one to two mapping of animal to feeding behavior for cat). Therefore, trying to use map now will throw `InvalidIndexError`:

```py
s.map(s2)
```

```
## Out
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

InvalidIndexError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-43-1950a0742767> in <module>()
----> 1 s.map(s2)


~/miniconda3/envs/ds/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in map(self, arg, na_action)
   3826         dtype: object
   3827         """
-> 3828         new_values = super()._map_values(arg, na_action=na_action)
   3829         return self._constructor(new_values, index=self.index).__finalize__(self)
   3830 


~/miniconda3/envs/ds/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in _map_values(self, mapper, na_action)
   1275                 values = self.values
   1276 
-> 1277             indexer = mapper.index.get_indexer(values)
   1278             new_values = algorithms.take_1d(mapper._values, indexer)
   1279 


~/miniconda3/envs/ds/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_indexer(self, target, method, limit, tolerance)
   2983         if not self.is_unique:
   2984             raise InvalidIndexError(
-> 2985                 "Reindexing only valid with uniquely" " valued Index objects"
   2986             )
   2987 


InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

---

You will need to check the duplicate values and decide which one to use. You can do it like this:

```py
s2[s2.index.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

```
## Out
cat    carnivore
cat    carnivore
dtype: object
```

In this case, both values of `cat` are the same and we can get rid of either one (which you description indicates is the same in your case). If they were different, you would have to choose which one to keep.

```py
# `~` negates/inverses the indexing
s2 = s2[~s2.index.duplicated()]
s2
```

```
## Out
cat       carnivore
dog        omnivore
rabbit    herbivore
dtype: object
```

`s2` now has a one to one mapping of animal to feeding behavior and we can safely map `s2` onto `s`.

```py
s.map(s2)
```

```
## Out
0    carnivore
1     omnivore
2    herbivore
3    carnivore
dtype: object
```

Comment: Very helpful Joe. I think my inexperience has shown, -  but more than helpful to have finally got to the bottom of it. I think I need to do more reading.